# How can I control the size of my generated asset when it contains transparent areas?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, generate-image-assets

I'm trying to use Photoshop's [Generate Image Assets](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html) feature to export a 32 x 32 transparent image with a solid 16 x 16 square in the middle:

[image: image screenshot]

My layers look like this:

[image: layers screenshot]

I'm using a fully transparent (no fill or stroke) rectangle that fills the area I want to be exported. This doesn't work, as the Generate Image Assets feature does not appear to consider it when determining the size of the asset; I get a 16 x 16 image containing the opaque square instead of the full 32 x 32 image.

I have read about vector masks or layer masks possibly being a solution to this, but I don't really understand them that well, and my attempts to use them to solve my problem were not successful.

So, how can I control the size of my generated asset when it contains transparent areas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent image cropping when using Generate->Image Assets?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/116166/how-to-prevent-image-cropping-when-using-generate-image-assets)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just setting the fill colour of the bounds to a colour that would blend into the background and set the layer opacity for it to 1%. Not very nice, and so I'm not going to accept it as the answer in the hopes that someone comes along with a proper way to do it.

Comment: The answer is: Layer Mask. You can find a proper answer here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/116166/2332

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an empty layer mask to that inner square and it should export with the transparent area intact.

I believe this is the case because with the layer mask, there is now some kind of image data in those 'empty' pixels so they export along with everything else.